# What happens internally when a reference variable of base class points to an object of sub class in JAVA

Tags: java, class, object, inheritance, reference

`ABC a1 = new XYZ();`
Where XYZ extends ABC.

datatype is what tells us what a variable will contain.
What is confusing me here is how is it even possible to ask a reference variable to point something it is not a variable of?

And even if we can do it, whats that benefit of it?

How does it work internally. when we write
`ABC a1 = new XYZ();`

Comment: "to point something it is not a variable of" -> Yes it is.

Comment: Very broad question. Please read about *polymorphism* for example to see what are possible benefits.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle How?

Comment: @BartoszKP oh yes, I can somehow manage to digest the benefits. But want to know what happens internally

Comment: @SrujanBarai I completed my answer in order to show why `XYZ` is an `ABC`.

Comment: Do you want to know how the JVM handles "is-a" relations? Or what do you mean with "internally"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern gives you flexibility.

Example for a sort algorithm :

```
private List<Integer> myCollectionToSort = new ArrayList<>();
```

As `ArrayList` extends `List` (it semantically means that `ArrayList` is a sort of `List` so it **IS** a `List`), this line is valid.

For your algorithm, you may not need to know that `myCollectionToSort` is an ArrayList. Your algorithm will only use methods of the `List` interface.

Later, you find that an `ArrayList` makes a lot of useless operations and you do not want to use it anymore. As you never used specific methods of `ArrayList` but only methods from `List` interface, the only thing you will have to change is the `List` implementation :

```
//LinkedList is more adapted for "writing" operations.
private List<Integer> myCollectionToSort = new LinkedList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just think of it like this:

Given these two classes:

```
class ABC {
    int a;
    public void getA() {return a;}
}
class XYZ extends ABC {
    int x;
    public void getX() {return x;}
}
```

The compiler adds those two classes together:

```
class XYZ {
    int a;
    int x;
    public void getA() {return a;}
    public void getX() {return x;}
}
```

It is a little bit more complicated than that if there are any other visibility parameters than public and if there is overlap between the function- or variable names, but it is basically that. In the memory you have first the contents of the base class, then the contents of the derived class.

In the memory you now have the classes somewhat like this (each letter stands for one byte):

```
Class ABC: aaaa
Class XYZ: aaaaxxxx
```

So when you then access something like this:

```
ABC a1 = new XYZ();
a1.a = 5;
```

Then the compiler treats this a1 as if it was an ABC, which works, since both have the member variable a in the first four bytes of the object.

It won't let you do something like that though:

```
ABC a1 = new XYZ();
a1.x = 5;
```

This is because all Objects of ABC or any of it's derived types do have the member variable a in the first four bytes, but not all of them have x in the second four bytes. Only Objects of XYZ have x in the second four bytes. Thus the compiler throws an error here.

So if you write:

```
ABC a1 = new XYZ();
```

Internally it looks like this:

```
a1 -> aaaaxxxx (reference a1 points to a structure containing 4 bytes a and 4 bytes x)
```

Since a1 is of the declared type ABC (and the dynamic type XYZ) only the member variables (and thus the corresponding bytes) that occur in ABC are accessible. So though there are two member variables containing 8 bytes, the compiler only allows access to the first member variable (a) and not to the second one.